# Run gnome - command

Tags: gnome

I just installed some packages and after restart GUI won't show. I can login in terminal but I need command to start Gnome or better let it start automatically.

Comment: What packages did you install?

Comment: And what do you mean by "GUI won't show"?  Please be more specific.

Comment: Could you paste the contents of ~/.xsession-errors to a pastebin (for example paste.debian.net)? That might show something which is going wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: What you're looking for is called a "[Display Manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829108/what-is-gdm3-kdm-lightdm-how-to-install-and-remove-them)".

I will leave my old answer for posterity, but it has flaws and is not good advice.

---

The `startx` command will start up the X server (Base GUI component of Ubuntu), or will probably give you a specific error message as to why it's not starting up.

If you're left at the command line after each reboot, but are able to get to your desktop using `startx`, you can create a text file called ".bash_profile" in your home directory. Add `startx` to that file, and it should be executed every time you log in.

Answer (score 3):

If you want GNOME to start automatically, try installing gdm. GDM is the default X display manager (which provides the login screen, and launches GNOME on login), and it should automatically start on boot.

You can use these 3 commands:

1. To start Gnome:

   ```
   systemctl start gdm3
   ```
2. To restart Gnome:

   ```
   systemctl restart gdm3
   ```
3. To stop Gnome:

   ```
   systemctl stop gdm3
   ```

Answer (score 1):

In terminal do:

gdm