# Sound in KDE Plasma doesn't work

Tags: sound, kde

I have KDE Plasma installed on top of Ubuntu 16.04.  And the sound doesn’t work.  It works fine in Unity but not in KDE.  It worked when I first installed KDE, it broke either when I was trying to get Evolution to work with Exchange or when I was messing around with the widgets on the dock.  (The dock widgets are all also shoved way over to the left by the launch button.)

And it boots into the Unity login screen.

How do I go about troubleshooting this?  I'm a bit of a Linux noob.

Comment: Well, hard to tell without further information, but things you can check are: check if pulseaudio process is running, then check in "System Settings->Multimedia" if there is anything suspicious, e.g. muted sound, wrong device is selected, etc.

Comment: @AndriusŠtikonas I believe both Pulseaudio and ALSA are running.  At least if I type pactl list and aplay -l; I don't get any errors.  Under System Settings -> Multimedia everything seems to be fine except for "Notification Sounds" which has a yellow "!" icon.

Comment: Yellow notification sounds icon is fine. It's just the icon used for notifications and does not indicate anything bad. Do more programs appear in that screen when you play something, e.g. with VLC.

Comment: @AndriusŠtikonas Yes.  When I open Rhythmbox, it appears.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong. The only other advice I have is to try to create a new temporary user and see if it works/doesn't work there.

Comment: @AndriusŠtikonas Well you were right about that.  Everything works fine in the temporary user.  How do I fix the real user.

Comment: So it's a matter of incorrect config settings. Make sure everything in SystemSettings->Multimedia is exactly the same as in temporary user's SystemSettings->Multimedia. If you can't spot any difference. you can try temporary moving out some files from your ~/.config/ folder. Then relogin and see if it helps. This way you can try to identify which file is responsible. (Sorry for not being more helpful...)

Comment: By the way, choosing your login screen is described in https://askubuntu.com/questions/829108/what-is-gdm3-kdm-lightdm-how-to-install-and-remove-them.