# Alternative greeters for GDM?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, gdm

Where can I find some alternative greeters for GDM?

And if I wanted to change the lock / login screen to look more like the lock screen of Windows 10, how would I accomplish this?

Comment: There is a [GDM themes category](https://www.gnome-look.org/browse/cat/131/) on gnome-look.org. I'm not aware of alternative greeters for GDM, but you can [install a different display manager](https://askubuntu.com/a/829110/354663) if you don't like the GDM greeter.

Comment: @danzel Are there any gotchas involved with using lightdm with a gnome environment?

Comment: I don't know. I suggest you either ask a new question or try it yourself, maybe inside a virtual machine.