# Alternative Display Manager for easy login

Tags: gnome, lightdm, display-manager

I use currently Ubuntu with 2 Display Managers: GRUB and i3.
Currently, in order to change the manager I log out and have to press a very small icon in lightdm to switch between GRUB and i3.

I wanted to ask, if there is any environment I could use for login only which displays different Display Managers as separate icons, so that I only press one button (the icon of the manager) and enter my password. I really don't like to have to use touch pad to change Display Manager

thanks in advance.

Comment: grub is not a display manager.

Comment: yes, it is not. I intendet to write gnome instead of grub but had apparently a brainfart

Answer (score 0):

Grub and I3 are not Display Managers.
i3 is a Window manager and grub is the boot manager.
A display manager is basically the login screen you get when you are nearly in your Linux environment.

To get some help with installing an alternate Display Manager I recommend following the following link:
[What is gdm3, kdm, lightdm? How to install and remove them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829108/what-is-gdm3-kdm-lightdm-how-to-install-and-remove-them)

Comment: I clearly know how to isntall/remove Display managers. I was asking about one with specific feature.

Comment: and sure, I mixed up few things, like display/window manager and that I meant gnome and not grub (clear from tags)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you switch to i3 using the session option on the greeter.  I'm not sure which greeter you are using.  You describe GDM3 but you are using LightDM tag.  Is the button you press for getting i3 next to your password on the login (greeter) screen?  This is your session selection.  Do you keep switching between Gnome and i3?  It should default to the session you selected on last login.  I'm not aware of any greeters that allow you to select the session like you are requesting.  LightDM does have multiple greeters to choose from, but I'm not familiar with GDM3.

Please verify which display manager you are using:

```
cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
```

And you can check what session names are available at /usr/share/xsessions/ folder.

```
ls /usr/share/xsessions/
```