# Reasons for difference in freed spaces after package uninstallation

Tags: apt, package-management, uninstall

I have [installed a LightDM](https://askubuntu.com/a/829110/113797) over my RaspberryPi 3B+. During this process I was asked to confirm that additional 22 MB will be used:

[image]

When uninstalling exactly the same package only 770 kB of spaces was promised to be freed:

[image]

What am I missing? Why removing of just installed package returns 4% of previously occupied space?

Comment: Since you did not show complete output, you are asking us to speculate. It's likely that parts of the output that you trimmed away include the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually when you install a package you get other packages(known as dependencies) which are required by the desired package.
But on uninstalling only that specific package you mention gets removed. Hence the storage is still occupied by dependencies.
You will have to use sudo apt autoremove to remove dependencies. However it too doesn't remove all the dependencies you installed with a particular package in case they are independent packages in themselves.