# Ubuntu 20.04 Black screen on login with Displaylink Driver

Tags: boot, nvidia, login-screen, displaylink

I have a problem with displaylink driver on Ubuntu. Whenever I turn on my PC (cold boot doesn't change anything) if the display link hub is plugged in, Ubuntu just shows a black screen instead of the login screen. I have to turn off my laptop and start it without displaylink and then plug it in after I login. There are other weird issues with displaylink like laptop freezing if I disconnect screen and freezing if when laptop is restarted.
Laptop: Acer Nitro 5
CPU: Ryzen 5800H
GPU: Nvidia 3070M

Answer (score -1):

As per my comment on this question, I experienced a similar situation. I changed my display manager from gdm3 to Lightdm, with help from this askubuntu [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829108/what-is-gdm3-kdm-lightdm-how-to-install-and-remove-them), and this fixed my problem.

Edit: I am deleting my comment and moving it into my answer:

> I'm the same. Using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and a Dell DisplayLink. My PC has one monitor connected to the graphics card and there are two monitors connected to the DisplayLInk via USB. All three monitors work as expected once I have booted up. When I start the PC up, after a power down, the monitor connected to the graphics card is a complete screen of purple. The two monitors connected to the DisplayLink are both black - but I can see the mouse on all 3 screens. On the purple screen I would expect to see the Ubuntu login prompt. It is present because because I can log in by hitting Enter and P/W