# What is this screen at startup?

Tags: startup

I re-installed my nvidia server as all my setting had vanished. I followed instructions found here:https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/not-showing-nvidia-gpu-in-ubuntu-20-04/180557

when I rebooted. I had this weird screen, what is it and how do I get rid of it? Thanks in advance.

[image: startup image]

Comment: It looks like a `login` screen from a system that has two 'visible' users. Click on one wiith your mouse, respond correctly to the Password: prompt, and you're in.

Comment: What is an 'nvidia server'? It kind of looks like you are running Debian.

Comment: @waltinator, you may have taken my question too literally. I know it's a login screen, I've just never seen it before the updates I made. Normally I would be logged straight into to Ubuntu, this is not a ubuntu login screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screen you are seeing is the default lightDM look. If you want to learn more about lightDM, go to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829108/what-is-gdm3-kdm-lightdm-how-to-install-and-remove-them) AskUbuntu post.

If you don't like the default configurations this manager provides, you *could* change this manager to one like `gdm`. Follow the instructions [here](https://linuxhint.com/change-display-manager-debian-linux/) to do that.